# Javascript Validate input field?

Tags: javascript, validation

I need a Javascript which will validate an input field, allowing only numbers and 1 comma in it, and maximum 8 digits.

How can this be done doing javascript?

Like using it on the input fields KeyUp?

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Look into regular expressions.

Comment: What have tried or thought??

Comment: maximum 8 signs ?? what does it mean ?

Comment: I think he means 8 characters.

Comment: Can the comma be anywhere in the number, including the beginning or end?

Comment: For now I have used the pattern `[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]`, but that doesn't allow commas.

Comment: The beter should not be able to be in the start and in the end. Only in the middle.

Comment: @MarkTopper Yikes; have you checked out any regex tutorials or looked for existing examples? Beter?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have looked into regular expressions, but I can't seems to find anything about comma there.

Comment: It's very easy... http://jsfiddle.net/RJDk2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputfield = document.getElementById("ID of input");
var commalocation;
var commas = 0;
var signs = 0;
var nums = 0;
var chars = inputfield.value;
chars = chars.split("");
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
  if (chars[i] == ','){
    commas++;
    commalocation = i;
  }else if (chars[i] >= '0' && chars[i] <= '9'){
    nums++;
  }else{
    signs++;
  }
}
if (nums > 8 || commas > 1 || signs > 0 || commalocation == 0 || commalocation == chars.length - 1){
  inputfield.value = "";
}else{
  var inputvalue = inputfield.value;
}
```

Comment: No, i have not actually tested this, but where does he ask for the things you listed?

Comment: Better; still not a fan of not testing code though. Fixed the logical error and assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You should use existing `mask` plugins like this excellent one : http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/how-to-mask-input-with-jquery/